# best way to send JSON to the page at creation time

Tags: javascript, json, html

I need to send some data to a web page, ideally in json format and I wonder what method is considered best, and why. Overall what good or bad experiences and surprises you had with them.

1. `<script>var myJson = <? echo json_encode($myVar);
   ?>;</script>`

   advantage: the json is directly in javascript, were it will be used.
   inconvenient: `<script>` in the middle of html/dom is bad (js belong
   to .js files).
2. `<div data-myJson='<? echo json_encode($myVar); ?>'>`

   advantage: html5 data thing is easy to work with.
    inconvenient:
   bunch of data in the dom, it doesn't look elegant note: in *my*
   case, I can afford to ignore "old" browsers.
3. ajax everything.

   advantage: the json doesn't even need to be sent in this case, as it
   will be already available (no page change).
     inconvenient: not
   really an option as I would need to rewrite the full website.
4. instead of sending the full json, store it in the session and send a
       key.

   advantage: less data moving around
    inconvenient: the
       data/session couple needs to be kept track of, and I like my session to be kept clean and tidy. (even if user just close the page before the flow is
       finished) (which won't close the session).
5. Cookies.

   advantage: herr.. is reverse evil a good thing?  
   inconvenient: like session variables, but out of the cage.
6. Store the json in the session, and ajax it when the page is loaded.

   advantage: somewhat elegant conceptually. 
   inconvenient: heavy, as the ajax instruction has
   to be added to a js file, and the session has to be managed. (and
   cleansed. if the page load doesn't finish, the json will stay until
   I cleanse it or the session finishes). Plus the html header means more bandwidth, and the we have to wait for the success to use the object.
7. other?

edit: as there seems to be a bit of confusion, with option 3 "ajax everything" I was meaning *one* page load, and *all* content loaded by ajax, even if you go through menus, links to other pages, forms submit, and such. I consider a more traditional navigation, (pages sent by the server as new a pages), with a page doing an ajax request to retrieve some value (here, my json object) on the server, as point 4 "session", as the main data has to remain on the server after the page has been sent to be later fetched by the ajax request. I did add option 6 for this.

Comment: a variation(I.E. function call instead of variable assignment) of the first one is pretty commonly used (example: facebook) and it's JS that belongs to .js files not JSON. btw, you don't need the `JSON.parse`.

Comment: #1 looks a bit ugly, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work out, provided of course that the JSON object isn't going to change during the lifetime of the page.

Comment: Google on their Google Plus service uses something similar to the 1st suggestion you made in their `var OZ_initData` (You can see that if you view the source of the page), but the data isn't exactly JSON but somehow similar.

Comment: I'm indeed more interested in the *method* than *content* . @Esailija yes, no JSON.parse needed like this (unlike for a classical ajax response). Editing my question. thanx.

Comment: Why would you have to rewrite the whole website?

Comment: because I won't reload the page "menu", would need to loads "plugins" source on the fly (there are tons), and I don't know if we can even unload them (delete $.fn.extends.myFunky3Dplug; ?) (which would be needed for memory). Moreover, that means a template plugin (else, why the bother) and an "address" plugin (for back button), etc. I never tried to ajax flash objects either...
 
  tl;dr: time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I unhesitatingly recommend #1. You want to use your data in javascript, right? #1 is the simplest way and most direct way to ensure that your data exists, as a plain-old javascript object, when the page loads. I transfer data from the server side to the browser side all the time this way and it works beautifully.

You could arguably create better separation between your data and your UI by loading your data in an ajax call, but this is an additional http request, which will slow your page load.

Comment: +1 but explain how #1 is in any way related to UI. And if you replaced #1 with ajax calls, the code would end up a lot more complicated. If we assume #1 is used with JSONP style callback instead of variable assignment then there is no interaction with it, it is automatically sent to the proper handler.

Comment: Re: related to UI -- if you can't stand the idea of javascript in your html page, you could get something cleaner with ajax call. I personally would never do this.

Answer (score 0):

Been a few years since this was asked, but for anyone else who finds themselves here and curious, I've been doing a variation of option #1 for quite a while.  Additionally, Nike Plus does this as well.  When the page loads, Nike sets `window.np = {}`

I've never really found a convention I love, but I've tried:

`window.data`

`window.app.data` (inspired by Symfony, literally uses the attribute `app`)

`window.[app_name].data` (inspired by Nike Plus)

`window.initData` (inspired by Google+)

In my case, I overwrite these JS objects with Backbone models/collections when the main Backbone app loads.